# React native New Arch: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.swmansion.reanimated.NativeProxy.performOperations()'

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Upgraded to version: "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2" with New Architecture for react native 0.71.3

Getting the issue java.lang.NullPointerException: Here is the complete log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.swmansion.reanimated.NativeProxy.performOperations()' on a null object reference
    at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.performOperations(NodesManager.java:188)
    at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.onAnimationFrame(NodesManager.java:249)
    at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.access$000(NodesManager.java:42)
    at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager$1.doFrameGuarded(NodesManager.java:142)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1127)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:926)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:835)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1114)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8298)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)has context menuComposeParagraph
```